# Organise files in folders depending on their names in shell script

Tags: shell-script

I'm writing a `.sh` file which I run it in the parent folder `/parent_folder/` in the .sh I run a command which created a subfolder named `My_Sub_Folder` and inside it there are hundreds of files each file starts with `Myfile_` then there is a number then `_` then another number then many other letters, as a smaller example these are some of the file names:

```
Myfile_1_1_3423423_MY.my
Myfile_1_2_3242343_MY.my
Myfile_1_3_5645654_MY.my
Myfile_2_1_3242354_MY.my
Myfile_2_2_4534535_MY.my
Myfile_2_3_2365464_MY.my
Myfile_3_1_5464567_MY.my
Myfile_3_2_4364766_MY.my
Myfile_3_3_4564564_MY.my
```

So as shown all files starts with `Myfile_` then a number increment count then `_` then another count increment number, so what I want to do is create subfolders inside `My_sub_folder` so in the example above there will be three subfolders under it named `Myfile_1` , `Myfile_2` and `Myfile_3` where `Myfile_1` will have all files starting with `Myfile_1_*` and so on. Any advice on how this can be done?

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
myscript2.sh
DIR=$(pwd)
${DIR}/My_sub_folder
###I am not sure how I can then loop on the files and create the needed folders depending on their names as explained above then move them to the corresponding folder
```

Comment: Advice on what?

Comment: @roaima On how I can achieve this?

Comment: @roaima I've edited the question as requested, thank you.

Comment: @roaima No it's not, I recently got a linux machine at work to manage a medical machine  which generates files. So I am trying to make things easier to avoid repetitive work.

Comment: @roaima Thanks for asking and appreciate your kind assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this,

```
#!/bin/sh
#
for file in My_Sub_Folder/*.my    # Files end with ".my" suffix
do
    dir="${file%_*_*_*.my}"       # Strip the pattern off the end of the filename
    mkdir -p "$dir"               # Create the directory unless it already exists
    mv "$file" "$dir/"            # Move the file to the directory
done
```

You can then make the file executable (in this case I've called it `thescript`)

```
chmod a+x thescript
```

And then run it as many times as you need

```
./thescript
```

To see what's going on, insert extra lines starting with `echo`. For example,

```
echo "Creating directory: mkdir '$dir'"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I had to edit this `dir="${file%_*_*_*.my}"   ` to `dir="${file%_*_*_*_*.my}"   `

Comment: Is there a way I can run another shell script `myscript3.sh` inside each of the created folder, where I normally manually go to each folder and run it, like in `Myfile1` folder I will run it like this `myscript3.sh Myfile_1_ Myfile_1_mine` and in `Myfile2` folder I will run it like this `myscript3.sh Myfile_2_ Myfile_2_mine` and so on. Is it possible to add it to this script? If you prefer me to ask another question about it then I can do this.

Comment: Is `myscript3.sh` complicated? Can you add its content to your question?

Comment: @Tak you can do something like `shopt -s nullglob; a=("$@"); for i in "${a[@]/%/*\/*}"; do ...` (need to use #!/bin/bash though)

Comment: @Tak, "_I had to edit this_" in that case the sample files you have us didn't match reality. It's really important to give plausible days otherwise the answered given here may be less than optimal

Comment: @roaima when I used your answer `dir="${file%_*_*_*.my}"`  the returned results of folder names were not `Myfile_1` `Myfile_2` and so on, so I had to change it to `dir="${file%_*_*_*_*.my}" ` so that it returns the one I wanted. Can you advise me with a keyword to search for for understand what the "strip pattern" line means? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: `a='My_Sub_Folder/Myfile_1_1_3423423_MY.my'; echo "${a%_*_*_*.my}"` returns `My_Sub_Folder/Myfile_1`. That works for me so it must be that your filenames have a different pattern to the one you've shown in your question. Use `man bash` (or `man sh`) and search for `parameter%word` to find out more